# JQuery code to dynamically add style to anchor tag

Tags: jquery, html, css, anchor

I am building an anchor tag dynamically through my code.

```
 str += " <li><a href='" + hyperlink + "'>" + linkName + "</a></li>";
```

I want to apply the below style to this anchor tag on a particular condition.

```
style="pointer-events: none;cursor: default;"

If (somecond) { apply the above style to anchor tag }
```

Please suggest how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of condition ?

Comment: where is the style here?

Comment: why you not given any id or class to anchor tag

Comment: In some scenarios, I want to apply the style style="pointer-events: none;cursor: default;" The anchor tag is built through code, can you help me in applying style through code?

Comment: `<a href='" + hyperlink + "' style='pointer-events: none;cursor: default;'>" + linkName + "</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Use the jquery `.css()` function ([see docs](http://api.jquery.com/css/)), for example:

```
if(somecond) {
    $('a').css({
      "pointer-events": "none",
      "cursor": "default"
    });;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this.

```
If(Your Condition Matching Criteria)
{
   $("li a").css("pointer-events","none");
   $("li a").css("cursor","default");
}
```

but above solution  will do  this for all the page level anchor who is in 'li' tag so what you can do for specific parent element of li you can provide unique identifier and then can do like this.

```
If(Your Condition Matching Criteria)
    {
       $("#uniqueParentId li a").css("pointer-events","none");
       $("#uniqueParentId li a").css("cursor","default");
    }
```

Replace "uniqueParentId" with your provide unique parent Id value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").css("pointer-events","none");
$("a").css("cursor","default");
```

Hope this is may stisfy you